# Angular asyncValidator with BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating Angular form. In given example you can find my code. I'm trying to create multi group form with async validator.
Case is simple to validate if number exists on list. In real case this list will be fetched from server but for purposes of demo I just added two buttons.

If I use

```
{ asyncValidators: [DataDuplicatedAsyncFuncValidator(of([1, 11]))] }
```

to pass data. Everything works. If I pass observable from subject form is in weird state when its valid and invalid :)

Please help me:

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k4jvlu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Can you provide any details of the "weird state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the data that the input value is validated against, not the input data that is validated. As soon as the observable returned by the validation function returns a value, angular does not care about changes happening after.

Also, i think angular is waiting until the observable completes, the mixed state means that neither is true, because the validator did not complete yet.

This means to re-evaluate the validity, you need to call `updateValueAndValidity()` on the validated control.

here's the modified example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nmrymb

Note:

- i shared the observable through shareReplay, not sure that's necessary, did that wile debugging
- i added a take(1) in the validator function
- i added the `updateValueAndValidity()` on changes to the validation data

Comment: Not as elegant as i would like to have but its working. Great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the reason is your source of ids is never got completed. to complete it after one event you can use `take(1)` operator

```
 return existing$.pipe(
      take(1),
      ...
```

Comment: I didn't know about angular forms, I was debugging this and I found out exactly this. But I think OP wants to change the valid status whenever `existing$` changes - The playground has the buttons change existing$ and they expect the valid status to change. I wonder how can this be done with Angular forms, if it needs the async validator to complete?

Comment: you can request the ids once, you also can request the id on every input. it really depends on your situation

Comment: But in here the ids might not be a request, but an actual observable which changes over time. You shouldn't need to wait for the user to make some input in order to poll again the observable, right? Let's not carry over this discussion, as I'm not the OP and I don't know its needs, but I feel like Angular is not using Observables to their full potential (they are using it as if they were lazy promises)

Comment: if we are talking about asyncValidators, then it is true indeed. you can take(1), but on ids$ update you can call updateValueAndValidity(), which will revalidate the value